# Not matching 50 ohm impedance

Tags: rf, impedance, impedance-matching

For my RF circuit (868MHz), I need 50-ohm impedance. When I calculate the impedance as PCB manufacturer layer stack-up,  the impedance would be 66 ohms. How does this affect my RF circuit performance? What are the limits of impedance matching?

Comment: Lower impedance by reducing layer thickness or wider track

Answer (score 1):

I did only a rough calculation, but assuming a 50 ohm driver and load, you will lose about 5% of signal power due to reflection.